# How to adjust Collapsing Toolbar left margin?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using a Collapsing toolbar, and when collapsed it looks like this...

[image]

I've been trying to figure out how to control the left margin, marked in the picture in yellow.  Some here suggest I use `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` but that does nothing for me.  Anyone got a clue?  I've tried just about everything, on the toolbar, CollapsingToolbar and AppBarLayout.

Comment: Can you share your xml code?

Comment: The gap between the navigation button and the title is determined by the `contentInsetStartWithNavigation` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Mike M for supplying the answer. In your layout XML, set your toolbar to

`app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"`